# "Ties" in Bayesian Survival Analysis

Tags: bayesian, survival

I have been reading about Bayesian methods for performing survival analysis.  One of the things that struck me is that in the three or so books that I have read, there is no mention of handling ties between events, e.g. Efron, Breslow, or exact.

Is this complication limited to frequentist statistical treatments?

Comment: What kind of Bayesian survival analysis are you talking about ? Parametric ? Nonparametric ? Semiparametric ?

Comment: e.g. Cox Proportional Hazards.  I am wondering if it has something to do with the partial likelihood vs. the full likelihood.

Comment: Ties also affect Bayesian inference. The presence of ties in a sample may preclude the existence of the posterior distribution even under the use of proper priors [(see)](http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/steel/steel_homepage/publ/fernandez_and_steel_1998.pdf).